# Number of superincreasing sequences of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Let us define a [superincreasing sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superincreasing_sequence) of natural numbers $b_1, b_2, \ldots,b_n$:

$$
b_{i+1} > \sum_{j=1}^i b_j
$$

or, as we talk about natural numbers:

$$
b_{i+1} \geq 1+ \sum_{j=1}^i b_j.
$$

What is the number of such sequences with the following property:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n b_j \leq 2^{n+1}-1.
$$

A simple lower-bound estimate is $n+1$ - this is the number of superincreasing sequences which consist of powers of 2, i.e. $n$-combinations of set $\{1,2,4,\ldots,2^n\}$.

In case this is complicated to find simple exact formula, estimates will be interesting too.

**UPD 1**. Program generation showed the following results for the first values of $n$: 3, 9, 35, 201, 1827, 27337, 692003, 30251721... This is OEIS [A125792](http://oeis.org/A125792).

**UPD 2**. It seems the number I was looking for is discussed in the paper [V. Bakoev, 
Algorithmic approach to counting of certain types $m$-ary partitions](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2784047.2784235) (also available [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X03000967)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the sequence is described in details of [A125792](http://oeis.org/A125792). The number I was looking for is the same as the number of partitions of $2^n$ into powers of $2$, excluding the trivial partition $2^n=2^n$ (note there by Valentin Bakoev).

Perhaps the easiest practical recurrent formula is the following:
$$
T(n,k) = T(n,k-1) + T(n-1,2k)
$$
$$
T(n,0) = T(0,k) = 1
$$

Then the answer to the original problem is $T(n,2)$.

One can find even more discussion and references in the description of [A002577](http://oeis.org/A002577) which is $T(n,2) + 1$ (in our notation).

Answer (score 1):

I find $\begin {array} {c c} n& \text{sequences}\\1&3\\2&9\\3&35\\4&201 \end {array}$

which is [OEIS A125972](http://oeis.org/A125792).  The counting is suggestive.  For $n=3$ there are $9$ beginning $1,2$; $7$ beginning $1,3$; down to $1$ beginning wit $1,6$ for a total of $25$ beginning with $1$.  Similarly there are $9$ beginning with $2$ and $1$ beginning with $3$.  For $n=4$ there are $9^2$ beginning $1,2$; $7^2$ beginning $1,3$; down to $1^2$ beginning $1,6$ for $165$ beginning with $1$, and again $95^2$ beginning $2,3$ and so on.  It clearly needs some induction.

Comment: I generated all the sequences for small $n$'s and found a bit different numbers: 3, 9, 35, 201, 1827, 27337, 692003, 30251721... And this is [A125792](http://oeis.org/A125792).

Comment: Seems to be a bit of disagreement at $n=4$. Perhaps you could both check your calculations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Found the error and fixed